# Теряется файл в POST через FormData

Tags: ajax, post

Собственно при отправке формы FormData по данному коду:

```js
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    url: url,
    data: formData
 });
```

На сервере я получаю все что надо кроме файлов. При отправке файлы отправляются, но в итоге отсутствуют как в `$_POST` так и в `$_FILES`. При этом если в запросе поставить `contentType: false`, то все отлично работает, кроме как на IE11. Возможно в данном случае с файлами надо как то по особенному обращаться?

Смотрел в сторону `application/octet-stream`, но так и не понял как это применить к конкретному `input`.

**upd:** C `application/octet-stream` ошибся, он и так присваивается файлу, другое дело что он не обрабатывается и не попадает в `$_FILES`.

Comment: Нашел похожую проблему на [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) . Там решение сводится к тому что `contentType` устанавливается в `false`, дабы не потерять часть данных. Так же там есть фолбек на старые браузеры, возможно он сработает и для ie11 )

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov к сожалению ничего не помогло, IE отказывается отправлять нормальный POST с файлом.